# Does SQL licence expire for a single instance?

Tags: sql-server, sql, evaluation

I have two instances of SQL server namely Adventure and instance 2. Now  I cannot start SQL server from services for Adventure but the instance2 is fine. Once i go through the log file it showed SQL evaluation is expired.

Does SQL licence expire for a single instance?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is NO. You can run as many instances as you want on the same physical hardware. Were you, or are you running an evaluation copy?

You might need to properly register it. See here: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sqlsmalltalk/2012/05/12/remove-evaluation-edition-180-day-time-bomb-from-sql-server/

Comment: I am running evaluation copy,  one instance is running  fine  the second instance I cannot start and the logs shows  "  SQL Server evaluation period has expired."

Comment: I'm not sure why you are having trouble then. Try running setup again and creating a third instance and see if that one will run. Maybe something is corrupt in the second instance.